# Where are my lost cron jobs?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am trying to port the code over to a new server hosted somewhere else, and I want to know what cron jobs are running on the old box.

Where can I find these?

```
crontab -l

SHELL="/bin/bash"
0 0,6 * * * php-cli /home/mycompany/public_html/index.php cron get_review_data
0 0 * * * php-cli /home/mycompany/public_html/index.php cron save_stats
0 0,6 * * * php-cli /home/mycompany/public_html/index.php cron check_for_new_reviews
0 0,6 * * * php-cli /home/mycompany/public_html/index.php cron refresh_infusionsoft_token
*/3 * * * * php-cli /home/mycompany/public_html/index.php cron infusionsoft
*/5 * * * * php-cli /home/mycompany/public_html/index.php cron sequence
0 0,6 * * * /usr/local/bin/python3.4 /home/scraper/scraper.py
```

I've checked `/etc/cron.*` with no luck.

Where can I go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions called (get_review_data, save_stats, check_for_new_reviews, etc.) should be listed within the php code and python code, `/home/mycompany/public_html/index.php` and `/home/scraper/scraper.py`

Examining those files should show what's actually being executed.

Comment: I think he wants to know where the crontab is stored, not the scripts that are being run by it.

Comment: I suppose that's possible, in which case it would help to know what OS he's running on... How 'bout it Jacob, is that right and if so what OS?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to look at your crontab with `crontab -l`. The corresponding command for editing crontabs is `crontab -e`.

This command will edit crontabs that are generally in the directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`.

In this directory you will find files named after usernames owning the crontab.